# Cassandra error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'datacenter' while importing csv

Tags: python, csv, cassandra, copy, nonetype

I have set up a cassandra cluster with 3 nodes.

I am trying to do a simple export/ import using copy command, but it fails with the following error:

```
cqlsh:walmart> select * from test;

 store | date       | isholiday | dept
-------+------------+-----------+------
     1 | 22/04/1993 |     False |    1


cqlsh> use walmart;
cqlsh:walmart> copy test to 'test.csv';
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'datacenter'
```

I researched the error and every related link seems to point out to python problems.

I also installed python driver pip cassandra-driver. Inserting data manually works, but not through export/ import.

```
cassandra@cassandra-srv01:~$ python -c 'import cassandra; print cassandra.__version__'
3.6.0
```

Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

how can I fix this error?

the logs inside `$CASSANDRA_HOME/logs` don't have any entries regarding the error.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.7/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1152, in onecmd
    self.handle_statement(st, statementtext)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.7/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1189, in handle_statement
    return custom_handler(parsed)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.7/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1907, in do_copy
    task = ImportTask(self, ks, table, columns, fname, opts, DEFAULT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, CONFIG_FILE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.7/libexec/bin/../pylib/cqlshlib/copyutil.py", line 1061, in __init__
    CopyTask.__init__(self, shell, ks, table, columns, fname, opts, protocol_version, config_file, 'from')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.7/libexec/bin/../pylib/cqlshlib/copyutil.py", line 207, in __init__
    self.local_dc = shell.conn.metadata.get_host(shell.hostname).datacenter
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'datacenter
```

Comment: Solution: Specify ip instead of hostname and port while connecting:   cassandra@cassandra-srv01:~$ cqlsh 192.168.56.101 9042
Connected to fiap_cluster at 192.168.56.101:9042.

cqlsh> copy walmart.test from 'file.csv';
Using 1 child processes

Starting copy of walmart.test with columns [store, date, isholiday, dept].
Processed: 1 rows; Rate:       2 rows/s; Avg. rate:       3 rows/s
1 rows imported from 1 files in 0.399 seconds (0 skipped).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not so good, but i will try to contribute to the problem. i'm new in cassandra and had exactly the same problem while trying to import data into a cassandra table via the copy function. i connect to the server on which cassandra is installed through cqlsh installed on a virtual machine. so i have to specify the server ip address and the port while running the cqlsh command: # cqlsh ip_address port
i connected with the servername like that: # cqlsh myserver.example.com 9040 and i was connected and the copy fonction didn't work.

But connecting with the numerical ip address of the server (for example:

## cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9040) it has worked.

it was by pure chance, i have simply tested and it has worked for me.

when someone here can explain this fact it would be great!

Comment: thank you very much for sharing the solution. It worked by specifying ip and port while connecting like you suggested. I did specify it previously, but hostname instead of ip.

Comment: Same applied to me. I was connecting through 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1'.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the build of cqlsh that you are using, In that build copyutil is not using correct host to connect. It has been [fixed](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-commits/201607.mbox/%3Cfe01c229440a4ac6a05f776a666548ad@git.apache.org%3E) in the new releases. Just clone the [repo](https://github.com/apache/cassandra) and run `bin/cqlsh` and try the same commands.